# Complex dynamic column horizontally?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the first table as below

[image]

And Second table as below

[image]

And I'm trying to display in such a way at SSRS as below

[image]

Basically using first table to fix the number of rows and using second table to dynamically load the columns and fit the data accordingly based on the ID.

I've no idea on how to construct the design of SQL result in such a way to be able to be displayed as demonstrated

Is there any sample on the net which will lead me to the right way on this matter?

Comment: `join` them and use `pivot`.

Comment: Please don't post (Table structure, sample data, your code) as images, always post them as formatted text please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @First TABLE (ID INT, Description NVARCHAR(50), Amount INT);
DECLARE @Second TABLE (ID INT, Description NVARCHAR(50), Amount INT);

INSERT INTO @First VALUES
(1, N'Cash', 50),
(2, N'CC', 20);


INSERT INTO @Second VALUES
(1, N'C1', 10),
(2, N'C2', 20),
(1, N'C3', 40);

SELECT ID, FD AS Description, FA AS Amount, C1, C2, C3
FROM
    (
        SELECT S.ID, S.Description SD, F.Description FD, F.Amount FA, S.Amount SA
        FROM @First F FULL JOIN @Second S ON F.ID = S.ID
    ) P1
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(SA) FOR SD IN ([C1], [C2], [C3])
    ) P2
```

Result:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+------+------+
| ID | Description | Amount |  C1  |  C2  |  C3  |
+----+-------------+--------+------+------+------+
|  1 | Cash        |     50 | 10   | NULL | 40   |
|  2 | CC          |     20 | NULL | 20   | NULL |
+----+-------------+--------+------+------+------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/BZVIH32991)**

Update: Dynamic pivot

```
CREATE TABLE First (ID INT, Description NVARCHAR(50), Amount INT);
CREATE TABLE Second (ID INT, Description NVARCHAR(50), Amount INT);
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX);

INSERT INTO First VALUES
(1, N'Cash', 50),
(2, N'CC', 20);


INSERT INTO Second VALUES
(1, N'C1', 10),
(2, N'C2', 20),
(1, N'C3', 40);

SET @Cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(S.Description) 
            FROM Second S
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');
SET @Query = N'SELECT ID, FD AS Description, FA AS Amount, '+ @cols + '
FROM
    (
        SELECT S.ID, S.Description SD, F.Description FD, F.Amount FA, S.Amount SA
        FROM First F FULL JOIN Second S ON F.ID = S.ID
    ) P1
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(SA) FOR SD IN ('+@Cols+')
    ) P2'
EXECUTE (@Query)
```

**[Dynamic](http://rextester.com/QSC49301)**

Comment: is `C1,C2,C3` dynamically in your case? Because for my case C1, C2 or C3 will appear dynamically

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep That will work if you have many rows C1, C2, C3, C4 ...etc. You can mark this answer as accepted if it works for you.